# Instagram API - Redirection works for app owner's account only

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

Been going through this for, like an hour.I am kind of using a signin using instagram setup. When testing, When I login using the app owner's account, I get the required output. But If I login using any other account, I get a Page not found error as below.

I can add the codes here if necessary.I get the required output when I login as the app owner.(When I signin to the app using the app owners account.)

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Please, type your code and oauth2 link for you and another account, if they different.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it was that the second account I was trying to test had some issues. It was blocked by Instagram to use any apps or so. Weird. They could have returned a better error than a page not found error!